# Your settings were imported, but there were some errors. Visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Any one can help me to resolve this issue? Your settings were imported, but there were some errors.

> Error 1: TypeScript Specific: Unable to import property
> 'JsxEmitForLooseFiles' because it contains invalid data '2'.
>
> Error 2: TypeScript Specific: Unable to import property
> 'ModuleKindForLooseFiles' because it contains invalid data '0'.

Due to this whenever I try to open any CS file Visual studio get close forecefully.

moreover, I've try to repair the visual studio still same issue.

Comment: I just ran into this myself. Did you ever find a fix?

Comment: Reinstall the complete VS